# Writing in combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I have 3 `comboboxes`.
At first I imported the number of stations. Example `11650`, `13450` and `more`.
When the user selects the number from the first `combobox` After automatically according to the station number in the second `combobox` After giving the date. Because each station dates are different.

My question to you is how I can do so if the user enters the number keys, in the second `combobox` to show dates?

My Code is :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string MyConString1 = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=hydrodb;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=;";

        MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString1);

        string command1 = "select Dat FROM hydgod where Station=" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command1, connection1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        da1.Fill(dt1);

        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        comboBox3.Items.Clear();
        comboBox2.SelectedItem = -1;
        comboBox3.SelectedItem = -1;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string rowz = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
            comboBox2.Items.Add(rowz);
            comboBox3.Items.Add(rowz);
        }
        connection1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: just for clarification: You want to populate the second `ComboBox` with dates according to the chosen station number?

Comment: Yes, I want to populate the second and third combobox

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get all corresponding dates into a `List<string>` and bind it as `DataSource` to the second `ComboBox`

```
List<string> dateList = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    dateList.Add(string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
}

comboBox2.DataSource = dateList;
```

**EDIT:**

> I received the same values result in combobox. 2010-01-01 12:00:00AM 
>   I want to cut the 12:00:00AM

If `row.ItemArray[0]` is of type `DateTime` you can try:

```
dateList.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd));
```

if it is a simple `string` you can split it:

```
dateList.Add(row.ItemArray[0].Split(' ')[0]);
```

ps. to populate the 3-rd combobox also you can just hook the same List also to the 3-rd one:

```
comboBox3.DataSource = dateList;
```

Don't add the items manually and then hook the list to the `DataSource`. Do either or

Comment: Copy your code in the method of combobox1, but it did not work.

Comment: @BlagovestPizhev What exactly does not work? do you get the wrong values? do you get no values at all? are you sure you get the right values from data base? did you check that?

Comment: By entering the code that I wrote, I received the same values result in combobox. 2010-01-01 12:00:00AM I want to cut the 12:00:00AM. 
I've try to write Date_Format(Dat, %Y%m%d) in the query but I received the same values again

Comment: @BlagovestPizhev Is the type of `ItemArray[0]` `DateTime` ?

Comment: dateList.Add(string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]));

Comment: @BlagovestPizhev I edited my answer according to the new information given by you. Check it out

Comment: Thank you, very much.. 
And to ask, how can I do so when a user enters on the keyboard number of the station in combo1,  combo2 and combo3 to charge dates? For now only when I choose with the mouse preset number of combo1, then loaded my dates in combo2 and combo3